# Electron JS: Windows frame is visible around BrowserWindow after focus lost

Tags: windows-10, electron, electron-packager

I'm currently working on an `Electron JS` application.
When running this application there is an animation to "deploy" the window and its reverse animation to close the application. So my frameless [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) is larger than its content.

One weird behaviour happens when the application loses focus. A frame around the BrowserWindow appears:

[image]

This behaviour only occurs when the [blur](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) event is raised.

Here is how my window is defined:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ frame: false, thickFrame: false, 
    width: 1000, height: 450, 
    icon: path.join(__dirname, 'assets/sharing-2.ico'), 
    transparent: true, titleBarStyle: 'hidden'});
```

Note that I don't have this behaviour when running an `npm start` command from Visual Studio Code but it does after I package my app using [`electron-packager`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-packager)